# R Subsetting nested lists, select multiple entries

Tags: r, list, nested, subset

I frequently work with large datasets, resulting in me creating nested lists sometimes to reduce the objects in the environment.

When subsetting such a list and wanting to go to the first entry along all steps, it would look like this:

```
llra[[1]][[1]][[1]]
```

In some of my current scripts the data in these scripts are aligned to that each of the entries of the last step down the list are comparable. If I would like to compare these or make a calculation it would look something like this:

```
mean(llra[[1]][[1]][[1]], llra[[1]][[2]][[1]], llra[[1]][[3]][[1]])
```

Is there a way to subset them differently so I could write it something like this:

```
mean(llra[[1]][[c(1:3)]][[1]])
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do the final elements of the list include? A single number, vector, data frame? `llra[[1]][1:3][[1]]` to subset list.

Comment: `llra[[1]][1:3][[1]]` will return first list of a list `llra[[1]][1:3]`

Comment: In my case, the final elements include rasterlayers but when doing this: llra[[1]][1:3][[1]] it only returns the first list of the three, like utubun said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map`.

```
mean(map_dbl(1:3, ~llra[[1]][[.x]][[1]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a small helper function. This creates a grid of indexes and extracts each one.  Finally it unlists the result.  No  packages are used.

```
unravel <- function(L, ...) {
  if (...length()) L <-
    apply(expand.grid(...), 1, function(ix) L[[ix]], simplify = FALSE)
  unlist(L)
}

# test

L <- list(a = list(b = list(1:3, 4:5), c = list(11:12, 20:25)))

# Example 1

mean(unravel(L, 1, 1:2, 1))
## [1] 5.8

# check
mean(c(L[[1]][[1]][[1]], L[[1]][[2]][[1]]))
## [1] 5.8

# Example 2

mean(unravel(L, 1, 1, 1:2))
## [1] 3

# check
mean(c(L[[1]][[1]][[1]], L[[1]][[1]][[2]]))
## [1] 3
```

### Update

Generalize unravel so that it does not assume three levels or which level(s) are specified as scalar or vector indices.

Comment: could you please shed some light into what ...length() does?

Comment: It is the number arguments passed as ... .  See ?...length   If we call unravel(L) then expand.grid will fail so we handle that case separately.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers, both Grothendieck's and Novotny's approaches work.
I simplified my example and since I am using raster layers in the last step of the list I made it work like this:

unravel method:

```
mean(stack(unravel(llra, 1, 1:3,1)))
```

map method:

```
mean(stack(map(1:3, ~llra[[1]][[.x]][[1]])))
```

It seems like a basic thing, strange that this isn't implemented in R yet.